# How best to collapse two factors with NAs into one variable

Tags: r

I have lots of sets of variables like this:

```
   Var1    Var2
"Asian"      NA
     NA  "Black"
"White"      NA
```

I would like to conveniently get them into this form:

```
   Race
"Asian"
"Black"
"White"
```

I have been trying something like:

```
Race <- ifelse(is.na(Var1), Var2, Var1)
```

But this converts the values into numbers for the levels, and the numbers don't match up (e.g., that yields `1, 1, 2`).  Is there a convenient way to do this (ideally with short, self-explanatory code)?  (You can get out of this with `as.character`, but there has to be a better way.)

Comment: Do you have to work with factors? Using character representations you could do: `pmax(Var1,Var2,na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @thelatemail, I just tried that, but it isn't working for me. Do I need to apply `as.character` to all variables first?

Comment: @thelatemail, it seems to work if I do `as.character` first. If you can tuck this into a convenient function, I'll accept it.

Comment: what about `na.omit(c(t(as.matrix(dat))))` using `dat` from the answer below

Comment: @rawr, this is a simplified example. I have a huge data frame, so I can't operate over it that way. The function works well, though.

Comment: You can also use unite from tidyr!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an intermediate conversion via `as.character`:
Assuming this is your data:

```
dat <- data.frame(Var1=c("Asian",NA,"White"),Var2=c(NA,"Black",NA))

do.call(pmax,c(lapply(dat,as.character),na.rm=TRUE))
#[1] "Asian" "Black" "White"
```

If you need to work on a particular subset you can do:

```
do.call(pmax,c(lapply(dat[c("Var1","Var2")],as.character),na.rm=TRUE))
```

---

An alternative not requiring `as.character` would be:

```
dat[cbind(1:nrow(dat),max.col(!is.na(dat)))]
#[1] "Asian" "Black" "White"
```

Comment: Actually, my data frame has many, many sets of variables like this. So I can't operate over the entire df this way. I wrote a simple function: `collapse <- function(v1, v2) pmax(as.character(v1), as.character(v2), na.rm=T)`, which seems to work though.

Comment: Neat idea! This might generalize slightly better to situations in which more than two columns need to be collapsed into one: `apply(df[c("Var1",  "Var2")], 1, max, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, in my case, there will always be 2 variables. If you want to write a function that will expand to >2 columns conveniently, I'll upvote it, though.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien - `pmax` will work just fine with `n` number of inputs - `pmax(1:3,2:4,3:5)`

Comment: Right you are. Very nice to know.

Answer (score 2):

What about this solution?:

```
ind <- apply(df, 1, function(x) which(!is.na(x)))
df[cbind(seq_along(ind), ind)]
[1] "Asian" "Black" "White"
```

Comment: This can probably be simplified to `df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), is.na(df$Var1) + 1)]` (at least in the case of 2 columns).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (quite weird I agree and quite short, your columns need to be character as it seems to be in your example):

```
> library(tidyr)
> unite(replace(df, is.na(df), ""), V, c(Var1, Var2), sep=''))$V
#[1] "Asian" "Black" "White"
```

Or, it may be risky to use gsub but here NA is a part of a character chain so safe:

```
> gsub("NA", "", unite(df, V, c(Var1, Var2), sep='')$V)
#[1] "Asian" "Black" "White"
```